# OWASP HTML Sanitizer allow colon in HTML

Tags: jakarta-mail, xss, owasp, html-sanitizing

How can I allow `:` sign in sanitized HTML? I am using it to sanitize HTML code in generating java mail. This code has an inline image content id like `<img src=\"cid:image\"  height=\"70\" width=\"70\" />`. Upon sanitizing, the `src` attribute is not included in the sanitized html.

```
    PolicyFactory IMAGES = new HtmlPolicyBuilder().allowUrlProtocols("http", "https")
            .allowElements("img")
            .allowAttributes("src").matching(Pattern.compile("^cid[:][\\w]+$"))
            .onElements("img")
            .allowAttributes("border", "height", "width").onElements("img")
            .toFactory();

    String html = "<img src=\"cid:image\"  height=\"70\" width=\"70\" />";
    final String sanitized = IMAGES.sanitize(html);

    System.out.println(sanitized);
```

The output of above code is:

```
<img height="70" width="70" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Why it isn't working

#### Or rather, why it's working "too well"

By default, `HtmlPolicyBuilder` disallows URL protocols in `src` elements.  This prevents injections such as

```html
<img src="javascript:alert('xss')"/>
```

which could potentially lead to the execution of the script after `javascript:` (in this case, `alert('xss')`)

There are other protocols (on other elements) that can lead to similar issues:

Even though it doesn't use the `javascript` protocol, it's still possible to inject a base64-encoded XSS injection:

```html
<object src="data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgneHNzJyk8L3NjcmlwdD4="/>
```

or

```html
<a href="data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgneHNzJyk8L3NjcmlwdD4=">Click me</a>
```

Because of this, `HtmlPolicyBuilder` assumes that *any* attribute value containing a colon (in certain attributes) should be treated as dangerous.

---

#### How to fix it:

You have to explicitly tell the `HtmlPolicyBuilder` to allow the **cid** "protocol", using the [`allowUrlProtocols` method](https://rawgit.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/master/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilder.html#allowUrlProtocols(java.lang.String...)):

```java
    PolicyFactory IMAGES = new HtmlPolicyBuilder().allowUrlProtocols("http", "https")
            .allowElements("img")
            .allowUrlProtocols("cid") // Specifically allow "cid"
            .allowAttributes("src").matching(Pattern.compile("^cid[:][\\w]+$"))
            .onElements("img")
            .allowAttributes("border", "height", "width").onElements("img")
            .toFactory();

    String html = "<img src=\"cid:image\"  height=\"70\" width=\"70\" />";
    final String sanitized = IMAGES.sanitize(html);

    System.out.println(sanitized);
```

**Output:**

```html
<img src="cid:image" height="70" width="70" />
```